# Java fireTableRowsInserted(int, int) with RowSorter

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table model which extends AbstractTableModel and a database that is being used for that model. Some processes are adding rows dynamically to that model and fire fireTableRowsInserted(lastRow, lastRow) every time when a row is added to database. Everything is working fine unless i add a sorter to that model. After applying sorter, fireTableRowsInserted(lastRow, lastRow) is throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException where as rows are still adding to the model and are being displayed on GUIl.

All the processes/threads communicating with Swing Components are dispatching on EDT. Below is the full stack trace for that exception.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 281
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setModelToViewFromViewToModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:734)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted0(DefaultRowSorter.java:1063)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted(DefaultRowSorter.java:868)
at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4272)
at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4120)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4397)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(AbstractTableModel.java:231)
at View.AllData.CenterSection.DataModel$1.run(DataModel.java:143)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

That could be the possible reason for that exception? and the potential solutions as well. Its about 7-8 hours now that i am trying to get on this but found nothing working. Any help would be appreciating for me.

Thanks in advance.

Data i need to display is very huge, so, fireTableDataChanged() is very much expensive for me. Cannot go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you forgot the [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) dictum, "When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates."

Answer (score 0):

In a very similar situation of the OP, my code is this:

```
        glosEntryTableModel.addElement(ge);
        int index = this.glseTable.convertRowIndexToView(glosEntryTableModel.getIndexOf(ge));
        // int index = glosEntryTableModel.getIndexOf(ge);
        glosEntryTableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(index, index);
```

As you see, I've tried with both model and view coordinates, and yet I get the exception on calling to fireTableRowsInserted, as the OP.

Debugging, I've seen that fireTableRowsInserted in AbstractTableModel contains this code:

```
public void fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
    fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, firstRow, lastRow,
                         TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS, TableModelEvent.INSERT));
}
```

and Java API docs says that

> TableModelEvent is used to notify listeners that a table model has changed. The model event describes changes to a TableModel and all references to rows and columns are in the co-ordinate system of the model

so there is no need to translate coordinates if you're already using the model coordinates. As the OP, in my case the row is actually inserted to the JTable and that means that, even if it is inserted/displayed in a different row in the view than in the model, the number of rows should be the same, provided that no filtering is being done (which is my case, indeed).

At the moment, I can only think that some processing in the JTable or the TableRowSorter is being delayed, causing that fireTableRowsInserted actually names a row that doesn't exist (yet) in the view. But then, shouldn't that be precisely the reason to use that method? Could that be a bug in JDK?

I'm using a relatively small model, so I think I can woraround with TableDataChanged for the time being, but I'd like to find a better solution, too.

TIA

Update: just realized that I have pretty much the same code in the same form for other JTable and that doesn't fail. The only difference is that this second table contains only a couple of rows, whereas the other whose code I've quoted and triggers the exception manages right now about 200 rows. So I'm leaned towards the idea of deferred processing by JDK causing the exception.